# Simple search engine issues

Tags: jquery

Simple search engine issues..

I'm creating a simple search engine but i'm not able to figure out how to go about it.
So here's what I have tried.

I need to get the results based on first/last name..

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WSPbP/

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sbutn').click(function() {
        $v = $('#searchbox').val();
        console.log($('#myConnections >div').find("div:contains("+$v+")"));
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="searchelement">
    <div class="search"><input type="text" name="search" id="searchbox" value="" /></div>
    <div class="searchbutton" id="sbutn"><button type="button">Search</button></div>
</div>
</br>
<div id="myConnections">

    <div class="left" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
        <img style="width:70px; height:70px;" src="picture1.jpg" alt=""><br>
    person1_xyz         

    </div>

    <div class="left" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
        <img style="width:70px; height:70px;" src="picture2.jpg" alt=""><br>
    person2 abc         

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is? What is the problem?

Comment: so you got issues... what exactly?

Comment: i'm  not able to figure out how to search for text and if present do something

Comment: if i type person2 it should search through the divs but console.log($('#myConnections >div').find("div:contains("+$v+")")); doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to quote the value in `:contains`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#sbutn').click(function() {
      $v = $('#searchbox').val();
      console.log($('#myConnections').find("div:contains('"+$v+"')").text());
   });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WSPbP/7/)